# How do you return a value that is dependent on the result of a co-routine that is started within the method? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a public method that returns a bool. The method starts a co-routine. The co-routine is what determines the value of the bool. I just realized that the method will return the bool without waiting for the coroutine to finish. I am at a loss on how to achieve this.

An example. Let's say a separate class is calling this:

```
public bool CheckListForName(string username)
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadPlayer(username));
    return playerExists;
}
```

I realize this code is meaningless without context, but if the bool "playerExists" is set to "False" by default, but the coroutine "DownloadPlayer" would find that "playerExists" should actually be true, it won't matter, because "CheckListForName" will have already returned "false" before the coroutine found the correct value.

I am relatively new to programming, so any help is very appreciated!

Comment: You have to wait for the co-routine to finish. This is basically what `await` does on an awaitable method.

Comment: The described behavior is only possible if you start a thread somewhere in `DownloadPlayer` or through `StartCoroutine`. Do you?

Comment: @Fildor you mean like having nested coroutines?

Comment: There are no "coroutines" in C#. Is this Unity?

Comment: @madreflection I didn't even know about "await" until today, but I am unable to get it to work. It seems I need a definition for "GetAwaiter" or something.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, Unity. So is "StartCoroutine" just a Unity class, and not part of C#. I didn't know that. Really? No coroutines in C#?

Comment: It's a Unity-thing, yes.

Comment: @madreflection You seem to have noticed on the spot, it's unity. Can you give OP an example of how to wait for a coroutine? I don't have a clue of unity, I am afraid.

Comment: @Fildor: I, too, am unfamiliar with Unity, except for what I've gleaned from questions on SO. Apparently, though, Unity co-routines are iterator methods, so it uses `yield return` to break out of an iterator state machine instead of `await` to break out of an async state machine. Yuck. It clearly pre-dates async/await. Unity tends to be behind C# compiler advances. [FYI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Comment: @madreflection Well, it's not _called_ "coroutines". I consider that a completely (well ... ) different concept and any non-unity-savvy C# dev will probably have a ? above his head... So, let's call the unity stuff "coroutines" and the .net stuff "task based async pattern", if you agree.

Comment: @BenMora: C#'s `async` keyword makes a method into a first-class co-routine. Unity, however, does co-routines using a mechanism that was never designed for that purpose. If you can use `async` and `await`, that would be better, but it tends to "infect" code and the sync<->async transitions would involve code that's generally advised against because it could create deadlocks. Either read the Unity docs to see how to wait for a co-routine to finish, or redesign your method and its caller to work with a callback. Unfortunately, I can't advise you on either.

Comment: I just don't want to cause even more confusion by using the terms interchangeably.

Comment: You make a good point. Nevertheless, I believe I've been very clear about the distinction and have advised the OP properly and responsibly.

Comment: @madreflection Absolutely. I didn't mean to suggest that you did otherwise.

Comment: Going through [StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) docs, I was wondering if `StartCoroutine` is actually what you want? It would have to yield execution and return to the main thread until the next frame. But are you frame-dependend here? Not really, right? So I was thinking if it weren't better to use a plain old thread (if not async/await)? I hope some unity-savvy community member can shed a light.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this everyone! I now know what I don't know, which is an amazing place to be! I will dig into all this "sync/async/await" stuff everyone's talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using async/await

```
public async Task<bool> CheckListForName(string username)
{
    await DownloadPlayer(username);
    return playerExists;
}
```

then to call the method

```
if(await CheckListForName("foo"))
   DoSomething();
```

or

```
var playerExistsTask = CheckListForName("foo"); //doesn't wait for task to finish here
Dothings();
bool playerExists = await playerExistsTask;//waits here
```

Comment: It will be nice, if you add [some link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for further reading

Comment: Mind that this (first snippet) would mean `DownloadPlayer` has the **sideeffect** of setting the `playerExists` Field. Which is neither obvious, nor desireable. So recommendation would tend to go for something like the last snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried both of these methods with no luck. I keep getting different versions of this error message: " 'IEnumerator/bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerator/bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: It's Unity. The Method returns a `Coroutine` instance. Have a look into unity manuals to find a solution. In Vanilla .Net/C#, there are no ["coroutines"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Comment: ^^ As @madreflection states correctly, there is a similar concept to unity's "coroutines". It's just not called that, so I would use the respective terms to avoid confusion.